# C# datatable, get NullReferenceException on Clear

Tags: c#, datatable, nullreferenceexception

i need help to understand why i get this error on a line in my code an not at a line where i would expect it.

I have a datatable object which i fill from a oracle select. 
After this i use this datatable as datasource for a datagridview. All fine.

I put all togehter in a methode to call it frequently from a timer.

```
    void fill_dgrsessions()
    {
        if (lst_connected.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {

            dt_aktsessions.Clear();
            dt_aktsessions = l_dbconn[lst_connected.SelectedIndex].get_sessiondata();
            dgrsessions.DataSource = dt_aktsessions;
            lbl_sessions_title.Text = "Sessions in der DB: " + l_dbconn[lst_connected.SelectedIndex].get_dbname();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Keine der aktiven DB's ausgewählt!");
            chkbox_autorefresh.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

When the target DB goes offline, i get the error in the line

```
dt_aktsessions.Clear();
```

why? I would expect this error in line:

```
dt_aktsessions = l_dbconn[lst_connected.SelectedIndex].get_sessiondata();
```

Thanks for your time and advices.

Marcel

Comment: where have you declared this variable dt_aktsessions?

Comment: this is a global variable in the class

Comment: Its not accessible or you haven't initialized.